# Four different verbs meaning "to release": 放す, 放つ, 解き放す, 解き放つ

Tags: word-choice, nuances, verbs

Consider the following four verbs:

- 放{はな}す - *hanasu* ([view in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%94%BE%E3%81%99))
- 放{はな}つ - *hanatsu* ([view in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%94%BE%E3%81%A4))
- 解{と}き放{はな}す - *tokihanasu* ([view in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%8D%E6%94%BE%E3%81%99))
- 解{と}き放{はな}つ - *tokihanatsu* ([view in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%8D%E6%94%BE%E3%81%A4))

Apparently, they all can mean "release, set free". What are their differences, if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you shoot, dispatch or emit, you usually *hanatsu*.  Arrows, light, smells and spies are things you *hanatsu*.

If you're setting them free from captivity, I think it's more appropriate to *hanasu*.  Captured fish, poor bound doggies or (more poetically) tied baloons are things you may *hanasu*.

However, there's some degree of interchangeability; both words may be used like the other.  As expected from the scheme above, right now there's 12100 矢を放つ on Google Books, vs. only 6 矢を放す ; likewise, 7 魚を放つ vs. 429 魚を放す.  (There are, however, a lot of examples of 犬を放つ； but, from a cursory look, they seem to be more like "set the dogs (on rabbits, etc.)").

解く is "to unfasten".  解き放つ therefore puts extra emphasis on the "freeing from captivity" nuance: to unbound them and set them free.  解き放す seems to be functionally a synonym.  Some things people are 解き放すing right now on twitter: curses, myself from the feeling of being locked, your passions, magical swords (from seals), saved money, my gayness, myself from mental tension.  Things people are 解き放つing: my feelings of gratitude, newly-released fashion products, the tension of athletes (through smiles), my comrades, The Invincible Sword, myself from the restraints of modern age, dragons from their fetters, prisoners.  I don't think there's a clear pattern in using one vs. the other, except that 解き放つ is a lot more common.  Many of the examples feel like English "unleash" to me.

(I'm not a native speaker; this answer is based on dictionaries and online searches. I'm only answering because no one did so far; if a native speaker says otherwise, they're right and I'm wrong.)

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much. +2 if I could. Sorry to take long to come and give feedback.