# A word to express a feeling of sudden release from intense pressure that had been building up over time

Tags: translation, expressions

I'm failing to express an emotion in Japanese that one feels after something emotionally unnerving that had been intensifying was then suddenly released, primarily due to being resolved by the subject. I was thinking of 「圧力解放」 but it feels like a direct translation from English and might not be understood by native speakers. Is there a better word or expression for that?

I also found [a question about 「解き放つ」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46622/four-different-verbs-meaning-to-release-%E6%94%BE%E3%81%99-%E6%94%BE%E3%81%A4-%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%8D%E6%94%BE%E3%81%99-%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%8D%E6%94%BE%E3%81%A4/46623#46623) that might be one showing the right expression but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun that represents this feeling, or a verb to describe feeling this way?

Comment: Both a noun and a verb would do. In that particular conversation I needed a noun, but I'm not sure if it's relevant. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me, who is a Japanese-speaker, 「圧力開放{あつりょくかいほう}」 is **not** a word describing a human emotion.  It is only a technical term meaning "pressure release".  I would not use it myself, but you are not me.

Here are some phrases that could be used naturally with Japanese-speakers.

***Nouns & Noun Phrases:***

・「解放感{かいほうかん}」

・「心{こころ}が休{やす}まる感{かん}じ」

・「解放された/[解]{と}き放{はな}たれた感じ」

***Verbs & Verb Phrases:***

・「解放される」

・「解き放たれる」

・「ほっとする」

・「安堵{あんど}する」

・「一安心{ひとあんしん}する」

・「気{き}が休{やす}まる」

・「緊張{きんちょう}が解{と}ける」

・「気抜{きぬ}けする」

There should be more, but I should not be working too hard during the Golden Week.